# Weyl semi metal vs entanglement entropy

Tags: condensed-matter, entanglement-entropy

In 2+1D, entanglement entropy (EE) is crucial for identifying a topological phase. 
What happens in 3+1d case? e.g. what are the behaviours of EE in WSM and trivial states?